# Procedure for obtaining a certificate of good behavior in UAE

Tags: uae, proof-of-employment

New requirements for getting a Visa include a Letter of Attestation and a Certificate of good behavior.  There are companies that will help with both, but with the latter, it's very expensive and I'd like to do it myself.  I can't find the information on the Internet about it.  (This is in Abu Dhabi)

Comment: Which visa are you applying for?